# How to update React state without knowing object key?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have several fields that are updating state. For that they will pass into function group key, key and new value. How can I update my state using passed variables?

This is what I tried:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
   firstGroup:{
      apple: '',
      cinnamon: '',
   },
   secondGroup:{
      apple: '',
      cinnamon: '',
   },
})

const updateState = (groupKey, key, newValue) => {
    const newState = {
        ...manualRange,
        [groupKey][key]: value,
    };
    setState(newState);
  };
```

As you can see I'm targeting either apple or cinnamon keys, which are located in either first or second group. So idea is to pass group and key into function, but I don't know how to update existing object with new values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for your `updateState` function:

```js
const updateState = (groupKey, key, newValue) => {
    const newState = {
        ...manualRange,
        [groupKey]: {
            ...manualRange[groupKey],
            [key]: value,
        },
    };
    setState(newState);
  };
```

I'm assuming `manualRange` is a reference to the existing state in this context. Otherwise, you probably want to use `state` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [firstGroup, setFistGroup] = useState({apple: '', cinnamon: ''};
const [secondGroup, setSecondGroup] = useState({apple: '', cinnamon: ''};

const updateState = (groupKey, key, newValue) => {
if(groupKey === 'first') {
  setFirstGroup({...firstGroup, [key]: newValue});
 else {
  setSecondGroup({...secondGroup, [key]: newValue});
 };
}
```

But for complex state it is recommended to use `useReducer` https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer